# keep only year month and day in datetime dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

Could anyone help me to delete the hours and minutes from this datetimes please?
I used this code but it stills returning the same output!

```
data["expected_Date"]=pd.to_datetime(data["Last_Date"]+ timedelta(days=365*2.9),format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

but it returns always this type 2019-01-22 12:00:00 but I want to keep only this 2019-01-22
how can I manage with that please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data["expected_Date"].dt.date
```